# Adjusting shape of a data array to perform optimization in SciPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have a code which performs optimization to infer a parameter:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd
    
    
d = {'Week': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    
def peak_infections(beta, df):
    
    # Weeks for which the ODE system will be solved
    weeks = df.Week.to_numpy()
    
    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    #reproductive no. R zero is beta/gamma
    gamma = 1/7 * 7 #rate should be in weeks now
    # A grid of time points 
    t = np.linspace(0, weeks[-1], weeks[-1] + 1)
    
    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ
    
    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T
    
    return I/N
    
def residual(x, df):
    
    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df)[1:] - incidence) ** 2)
    
x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, args=(df), method="Nelder-Mead").x
print(res)
```

However, it is not giving the correct values, so instead of taking weeks as 1,2,3... in the line `d = {'Week': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}` I'd like to use days instead so Python has clearer information to work with. I'd like to slice the `linspace` of days as weekly intervals. However, I'm having some shape alignment issues:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd
    
time = np.linspace(0, 77, 77 + 1)
d = {'Week': [time[7],time[14],time[21],time[28],time[35],time[42],time[49],time[56],time[63],time[70],time[77]], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
#d = {'Week': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    
def peak_infections(beta, df):
    
    # Weeks for which the ODE system will be solved
    weeks = df.Week.to_numpy()
    
    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    #reproductive no. R zero is beta/gamma
    gamma = 1/7 * 7 #rate should be in weeks now
    # A grid of time points 
    t = np.linspace(0, 77, 77 + 1)
    
    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ
    
    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T
    
    return I/N
    
def residual(x, df):
    
    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df)[1:] - incidence) ** 2)
    
x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, args=(df), method="Nelder-Mead").x
print(res)
```

The approach I tried here was recreating the dataframe by slicing `time` which is 77 days, so 11 weeks. It still returns that the shape error, 77 against 11 elements occurs within my function `residual` in the line `return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df)[1:] - incidence) ** 2)`. Where is my approach going wrong?

-----------EDIT----------
updated code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd

t = np.arange(7,84,7)
d = {'Week': t, 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
#d = {'Week': [time[7],time[14],time[21],time[28],time[35],time[42],time[49],time[56],time[63],time[70],time[77]], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
#d = {'Week': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def peak_infections(beta, df):

    # Weeks for which the ODE system will be solved
    weeks = df.Week.to_numpy()

    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 10, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    S0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    #reproductive no. R zero is beta/gamma
    gamma = 1/7 * 7 #rate should be in weeks now
    # A grid of time points 
    t = np.linspace(0, 77, 77 + 1)

    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
        S, I, R, J = y
        dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
        dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
        dR = (gamma * I)
        dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
        return dS, dI, dR, dJ

    # Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
    S, I, R, J = solve.T

    return I/N

def residual(x, df):

    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df) - incidence) ** 2)

x0 = 0.5
res = minimize(residual, x0, args=(df), method="Nelder-Mead").x
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs at line 52, where you are getting 77 values by solving `peak_infections(x, df)[1:]` and you have 11 values of `incidence`, as you have mentioned.

This arises because you are solving your ode at `t` (line 29) which has 78 values. To avoid this, generate a time vector with 7 values in your `peak_infections` function as follows:

```python
t = np.linspace(0, 77, 77 + 1)
t = [t[7],t[14],t[21],t[28],t[35],t[42],t[49],t[56],t[63],t[70],t[77]]
```

or a completely new one as:

```python
t = np.arange(7,84,7)
```

and change your `residual` function (don't slice `peak_infections(x, df)[1:]`) as follows:

```python
def residual(x, df):

    # Total population, N.
    N = 100000
    incidence = df.incidence.to_numpy()/N
    return np.sum((peak_infections(x, df) - incidence) ** 2)
```

this will solve your problem as now you are comparing NumPy arrays with shapes (7,) and (7,) which will not produce an error.

Comment: What do i then do with the line `d = {'Week': [time[7],time[14],time[21],time[28],time[35],time[42],time[49],time[56],time[63],time[70],time[77]], 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}`? How should I construct the dataframe given this approach?

Comment: `d = {'Week': np.arange(7,84,7), 'incidence': [206.1705794,2813.420201,11827.9453,30497.58655,10757.66954,7071.878779,3046.752723,1314.222882,765.9763902,201.3800578,109.8982006]}`. This is much better where you don't need `linspace`.

Comment: Please see the edit code i added at the bottom. For some reason, it still returns shape based error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (78,) (11,)`

Comment: Inside the `peak_infections `, just before `deriv `, define `t = np.arange(7,84,7) ` instead of using `linspace ` and you will be good to go. See my answer again, I have mentioned this there as well. You need to solve ode at a `t ` containing shape (7,).

Comment: @Landon Did the above solution work for you?

Comment: Muhammad - many thanks, after some fiddling around, I got the linspace method of yours to work!

Comment: Glad that it helped :). If it worked then may be you should see [What should I do when someone answers my question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)