# How can I make selenium calls in Laravel 9 from selenium docker container?

Tags: laravel, docker, selenium

I want to make selenium web requests to real websites.

I managed to get [php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) work with a local installation of chromedriver. However, this has caused many problems for me, as having a compatible version of Chromedriver and Chrome is tricky and I run into a lot of session and timeout-exceptions.

This is how it works with the local chromedriver.

```php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;


// This is where Selenium server 2/3 listens by default. For Selenium 4, Chromedriver or Geckodriver, use http://localhost:4444/
$host = 'http://localhost:4444';

$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);

$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70976750/adjusting-shape-of-a-data-array-to-perform-optimization-in-scipy";
$driver->get($url);
```

I wonder now, can I use the selenium docker image that ships with Laravel 9 to make selenium web requests in my Laravel application without local installation of the chromedirver? If so, what do I have to specify for `host` in the above code?
If I leave the code unchanged, I get

> Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused

although the image "selenium/standalone-chrome" has "4444/tcp" as port.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
756f331870b4   sail-8.1/app                  "start-container"        2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8011->80/tcp, :::8011->80/tcp                                        laravel-flathunter_laravel.test_1
fa84b628f814   selenium/standalone-chrome    "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             4444/tcp                                                                               laravel-flathunter_selenium_1
0457fa502c43   redis:alpine                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp                                              laravel-flathunter_redis_1
d122fd0f4bcd   mysql/mysql-server:8.0        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp                             laravel-flathunter_mysql_1
aef91bbba6ca   mailhog/mailhog:latest        "MailHog"                2 hours ago   Up 2 hours             0.0.0.0:1025->1025/tcp, :::1025->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8025->8025/tcp, :::8025->8025/tcp   laravel-flathunter_mailhog_1
f0267f810dec   getmeili/meilisearch:latest   "tini -- /bin/sh -c …"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:7700->7700/tcp, :::7700->7700/tcp                                              laravel-flathunter_meilisearch_1
```

**Edit:** If I use `selenium:4444` then `RemoteWebDriver::create` fails with the following:

```
 Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException 

  JSON decoding of remote response failed.
Error code: 4
The response: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"consoleLink": "\u002fwd\u002fhub","type": "Standalone","class": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpHandler$DisplayHelpServletConfig","version": "3.141.59"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>'

  at vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:339
    335▕ 
    336▕         $results = json_decode($raw_results, true);
    337▕ 
    338▕         if ($results === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
  ➜ 339▕             throw new WebDriverException(
    340▕                 sprintf(
    341▕                     "JSON decoding of remote response failed.\n" .
    342▕                     "Error code: %d\n" .
    343▕                     "The response: '%s'\n",

      +1 vendor frames 
  2   app/Console/Commands/TestSelenium.php:37
      Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create()

      +13 vendor frames 
  16  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
ERROR: 1
```

Comment: As long as the containers are on the same docker network, you can use there name: e.g. `laravel.test`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε so using "selenium:4444` seems to work, but now I get a `JSON decoding of remote response failed.`error, when creating the driver. Its odd, because I didn't even start to request a page.